# Php - string to array 3 dimensions

Tags: php, arrays, string, sudoku, strsplit

I come to you to find a solution to my problem:

I have a flat string like this:

```
$chaine = "519637824467582931832419576721894365346125789985376412698243157273951648154768293";
```

I want to convert this dimensional array chain, this format here:

```
$tab = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
];
```

I had an initial response with `$ grille_splited = str_split ($ string, 9);` I get a table:

```
$tab = [
[000000000],
[000000000],
[000000000],
[000000000],
[000000000],
[000000000],
[000000000],
[000000000],
[000000000],
];
```

I'm missing a Dimension I believe?

For information: this question aims to use a Solver Sudoku ([Sudoku Projet](https://github.com/xeeeveee/sudoku))

*result of a google translate

Edit : Sorry Guy's and Thx for your tips ! :)

Comment: In English please. https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/

Comment: only English plz.

Comment: Recherche: english pulp fiction

Comment: very weird. Your question is in english and description in French

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform an aditional split on the 9 char strings:

```
$string = "519637824467582931832419576721894365346125789985376412698243157273951648154768293";
$output = array_map(function($element){
    return str_split($element);
}, str_split($string, 9));

/*$output equals
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 9
            [3] => 6
            [4] => 3
            [5] => 7
            [6] => 8
            [7] => 2
            [8] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 7
            [3] => 5
            [4] => 8
            [5] => 2
            [6] => 9
            [7] => 3
            [8] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 1
            [5] => 9
            [6] => 5
            [7] => 7
            [8] => 6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 8
            [4] => 9
            [5] => 4
            [6] => 3
            [7] => 6
            [8] => 5
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 6
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 2
            [5] => 5
            [6] => 7
            [7] => 8
            [8] => 9
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 3
            [4] => 7
            [5] => 6
            [6] => 4
            [7] => 1
            [8] => 2
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 9
            [2] => 8
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 4
            [5] => 3
            [6] => 1
            [7] => 5
            [8] => 7
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 7
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 9
            [4] => 5
            [5] => 1
            [6] => 6
            [7] => 4
            [8] => 8
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 7
            [4] => 6
            [5] => 8
            [6] => 2
            [7] => 9
            [8] => 3
        )

)/*
```